# Equivalent to command prompt's "tree" command?

Tags: command-line, windows, bash, find

Back in my (sucky) Windows days, I used the `tree` command to view the file hierarchy in a pretty display. I am aware of the `find` command, but to actually process any data in my clogged 241,416 folders/files from just checking each line is as possible as time travelling...

```
./build/CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache
./build/CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake
./build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
./build/CMakeFiles/TargetDirectories.txt
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/depend.make
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/flags.make
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/DependInfo.cmake
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/link.txt
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/build.make
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/cmake_clean.cmake
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/main.o
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/CXX.includecache
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/progress.make
./build/CMakeFiles/compilerid.dir/depend.internal
./build/cmake_install.cmake
./build/CMakeCache.txt
./build/Makefile
./build/compilerid
./CompilerID.kdev4
./.kdev4
./.kdev4/CompilerID.kdev4
./main.cpp
```

**Output of `find` on one folder holding the files of a one-file, incomplete C++ project**

On Windows, the `tree` command gave a diagram-like output that is *human readable*

[image: Screenshot of tree command in command prompt]
**Screenshot of the pretty `tree` command**

### So, my question is, is there anything graphically close to the Windows/DOS `tree` command?

Comment: there's a tree command for linux

Comment: @SylvainPineau Yes, by to search for it, it didn't have very similar wording, plus, Stack Exchange's search engines are so embarrassingly awful

Comment: I like that you specified that your Windows days were sucky (even though that goes without being said).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same command exist. To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

[image]

Comment: I know how to open up the Terminal ;-)

Comment: @Abdullah0v0 Nothing wrong with extra information ;) Besides, someone else who reads the question/answer might need that tip ;)

Comment: For better convenience, I'd pair `tree` with `less` when using it for easier scrolling functionality. `$ tree | less`

Comment: @Dan Excellent tip, you should edit it into your answer...

Comment: @dan then I would go for "most" :=D

Comment: @Dan Even better: `tree -C | less -R` preserves colours.

Comment: @Bakuriu Didn't know about the `-R` switch. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You have tree command in linux. All you have to do is install it. It works very similar to the one in windows.

`sudo apt-get install tree`